# Call a function when I access a property (PHP magic methods)

Tags: php, magic-methods

basically I'm using PHP Overloading to create dynamic methods and properties. What I want to do is to trigger a function to a property access but keeping the access to its methods.

In other terms, that's my PHP code:

**First Class:**

```
class _class {
    private $_instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_instance = new _object();
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        switch ($name) {
            case "instance":
                //LOGICS
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Second Class:**

```
class _object {
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        switch ($method) {
            case "method":
                //LOGICS
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I want to execute a function when I access to an object property in this way:

```
$obj = new _class();
echo $obj->instance; //some output here, executing a function
echo $obj->instance->method(); //different output, executing the method of the instance
```

Thanks, an help will be really appreciated!

Comment: And the results? What did you get? Did you get what you want? or what?

Comment: Accessing the property works fine and the code reaches the switch, but I'm missing the part to call a function if `$obj->instance->somemethod()` is called instead of `$obj->instance`.

Comment: Still unclear for me. What tests did you run, what output you get, what's the purpose of all this

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate the first class, then you create a `$this->_instance` instead `$obj->instance`. `So $obj->instance` will be `null` and can not call anything on that.

But, if you try `$obj->_instance->method();`, that will be bad also, because `_instance` is private. So you need to add getter. Try this:

```
class _class {

    private $_instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_instance = new _object();
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        switch ($name) {
            case "instance":
                echo "Instance";
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getInstance() {
        return $this->_instance;
    }

}

class _object {

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        switch ($method) {
            case "method":
                echo "Method";
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

}

$obj = new _class();
$obj->instance; 
$obj->getInstance()->method();
```

Output is:

```
Instance
Method
```

Comment: Already done that way, but I want to keep the same sintax so I can call `$obj->instance;` and `$obj->instance->method();` and get the correct returns (so basically I want to avoid the getInstance() method and find a way to determine it programmatically)

Comment: But you have no `$obj->instance` object. That is a non existent property, this is why `__get` executed. You have only `$obj->_instance`, but that is private. You need to set it to public, and then you can call `$obj->_instance->method()` if you want to do it that way.

Comment: Yeah just wanted to discuss that idea with some others and maybe find a way to build something similar to the way C# Entity Framework access to data or execute methods on them. Setting `$obj->_instance` to public does not fit my request (probably unachievable) to keep the same name for the Instance access or the Instance Method access.